# phonegap error: log Tag:dalvikvm, Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse'

Tags: cordova, cordova-2.0.0

Use cardova 2.0.0. After Compilations app show error:

```
Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse.
```

- android:minSdkVersion="8"
- uses-permission - All

config.xml is.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing, ignore the log. I believe in 2.1.0 Joe is guarding against the method not being around so it should go away.