# PhoneGap 2.0 Upgrade Errors - JSCallback Error / Could not find class

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova

I updated my Phonegap (Cordova) project from 1.9 to 2.0 and am receiving the following two new errors:

```
Web Console

JSCallback Error: Request failed. at file file://android_assets/www/js/cordova-2.0.0.js:3698
```

and

```
dalvikvm

Could not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from method org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generatedWebResourceResponse
```

Is this a known problem? I have searched but can't find a solution that addresses these issues. I have tried creating a new blank project and I am getting the same errors. I have also ensured Eclipse and the SDK manager are up to date.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the first question as I need to know what you are doing when that log appears.

Regarding the second question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12043959/41679